# how to search item in listed element react native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, expo

I am stuck with a problem, when am trying to search elements from listed data it's not working, I seem lots of document ad I applied it, but still, its work for me, can anyone help me.
if you have any questions please free feel to ask any time.

> home.js

This is `Home.js` file where I wrote my all code. and here I use some React native paper components.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Text, View, FlatList, StyleSheet, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Avatar } from 'react-native-elements';
import { Searchbar, Provider, Portal, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native-paper';
import { AntDesign, Entypo } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import Modal from "react-native-modal";

export default function Home() {

  const [searchquery, setSearchquery] = React.useState();
  const [isModalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [name, setName] = React.useState('');
  const [number, setNumber] = React.useState('');


  const toggleModal = () => {
    setModalVisible(!isModalVisible);
  };

    const filterItem = (text) => {
      users.filter((item) => {
        return item.name.toLowerCase().inludes(text.toLowerCase())
      })
      setSearchquery(text)
  }

  

  const [users, setUser] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Ashish Nirvikar",
      number: 3289768909,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Drew Macntyre",
      number: 3345661276
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Jonh Cena",
      number: 9087392878
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Rock Samoa",
      number: 9723780928
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "Boby Lashely",
      number: 8769213678
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      name: "Seth Rollins",
      number: 6890326741
    },
  ])

  return (
    <View >
      <Searchbar
        placeholder="Search Contacts"
        onChangeText={(text) => setSearchquery(text)}
        value={searchquery}
        style={{ marginTop: 30, marginHorizontal: 10 }}
      />
   <ScrollView>
     {
          filterItem(users).map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <View key={index} style={styles.names}>
                <Text style={{ color: 'black', fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Name : {item.name}</Text>
                <Text style={{ color: 'black' }}>Mobile no : {item.number}</Text>
              </View>
            )
          })
        }
     </ScrollView>

      <Modal isVisible={isModalVisible} style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', height: 50, marginBottom: 200, marginTop: 100 }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 2 }}>
          <Text style={{ color: 'black', fontSize: 50, textAlign: 'center' }}>Add Contact</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            label="Enter Full name"
            value={name}
            onChangeText={text => setName(text)}
          />
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input1}
            label="Enter Mobile Number"
            value={number}
            onChangeText={text => setNumber(text)}
          />
          <Button title="Hide modal" onPress={toggleModal} style={{ color: 'black', backgroundColor: 'white', borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'gray', marginHorizontal: 10, marginTop: 15 }}>Cancle</Button>
        </View>
      </Modal>

      <AntDesign name="plus" size={34} color="black" style={styles.plus} onPress={toggleModal} />
    </View>
  );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  customText: {
    padding: 10,
    marginTop: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'lightgray',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 20
  },
  plus: {
    fontSize: 50,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 680,
    right: 40,
    backgroundColor: 'pink',
    borderRadius: 15,
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    padding: 5,
  },
  names: {
    padding: 15,
    fontSize: 25,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    backgroundColor: 'lightgray',
    marginTop: 10,
    borderRadius: 20,
    color: 'black'
  },
  addcontactname: {
    fontSize: 30,
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 30
  },
  input: {
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    marginBottom: 20,
    marginTop: 20
  },
  input1: {
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 const filterItem = (searchItems) => {
      searchItems.filter((item) => {
        return item.name.toLowerCase().inludes(searchquery.toLowerCase())
      })
    
  }


<Searchbar
        placeholder="Search Contacts"
        onChangeText={(text) => setSearchquery(text)}
        onClear={(text) => searchquery("")}
        value={searchquery}
        style={{ marginTop: 30, marginHorizontal: 10 }}
      />
   <ScrollView>
     {
          filterItem(users).map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <View key={index} style={styles.names}>
                <Text style={{ color: 'black', fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Name : {item.name}</Text>
                <Text style={{ color: 'black' }}>Mobile no : {item.number}</Text>
              </View>
            )
          })
        }
     </ScrollView>
```

Comment: getting an error text.toLowercase() is not a function

Comment: @MonuPatil here updated the code

Comment: @shafayat i have updated my my you can checkout now

Comment: @MonuPatil check my code now and apply it

Answer (score 0):

Your `Searchbar` should be a controlled input (call `setSearchquery` with the change value from the `Searchbar`).

Then you can use the value of `searchquery` to perform the filtering inline in your jsx.

Finally, use `FlatList` to render a list of items instead of a map inside a `ScrollView`.

In your example, there's no need for the list of users to be stored in state.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ScrollView, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { Searchbar } from 'react-native-paper';

const data = [...];

export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchquery: '',
    };
  }

  renderHeader = () => {
    return (
      <Searchbar
        placeholder="Search Contacts"
        onChangeText={(searchquery) =>
          this.setState({
            searchquery,
          })
        }
        value={this.state.searchquery}
      />
    );
  };

  renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <View key={index} style={styles.names}>
        <Text>
          Name : {item.name}
        </Text>
        <Text>Mobile no : {item.number}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={data.filter((item) => {
          if (!this.state.searchquery) return true
          return item.name
            .toUpperCase()
            .includes(this.state.searchquery.toUpperCase());
        })}
        ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

[Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@ksav/quiet-juice-box)

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this code if it will not work then call `filterItem` function with bracket and parameter also my code is working while the name is lowercase.

```
<Searchbar
    placeholder="Search Contacts"
    onChangeText={filterItem}
    onClear={(users) => setUser('')}
    value={searchquery}
    style={{ marginTop: 30, marginHorizontal: 10 }}
/>

const filterItem = (text) => {
    setSearchquery(text)
    let searchText = text.toLowerCase()
    let filterData = users
    filterData = filterData.filter(function (id) {
      return id.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)
    })
    setUser(filterData);
    if (text === "") {
     setUser(
[
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Ashish Nirvikar",
      number: 3289768909,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Drew Macntyre",
      number: 3345661276
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Jonh Cena",
      number: 9087392878
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Rock Samoa",
      number: 9723780928
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "Boby Lashely",
      number: 8769213678
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      name: "Seth Rollins",
      number: 6890326741
    },
  ]
);
    }
}
```

Comment: @novonimo  i also go through your code , in your code search text working fine , but when I am trying to cut on it , its not working

Comment: @MonuPatil obviously bcz we put condition if text will empty it will not reset the first users check condition in filterItem it will set last state users data

Comment: please let me know where should I update my code

Comment: updated code u can set users value same as initially you are giving if text is blank this will work I guess

Comment: @vivan i have updated but still getting an error like users not defined

Comment: @MonuPatil  please make this changes    onChangeText={(text) =>filterItem(text)}